# EJS getting JSON data with gulp

Tags: javascript, json, gulp, ejs

I'm using gulp to compile my ejs templates into an html file and I am struggling to find out how to tell it where my `json` file of data is.
When I try to use `gulp-ejs` like below

```
gulp.task('ejs', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/views/pages/index.ejs')
    .pipe(ejs(
      { media: 'src/js/data/data.json' },
      { ext:'.html' }))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});
```

It takes what I intend to be a path as a literal string. Is there a different way to do this outside of gulp, or within gulp that will pass it the json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a two-part issue on my part, I figured out the solution after some trial and error.

First I was importing my json file wrong, I ended up not importing it in gulp but when I imported it in my javascript file later I did it like below:

`const media = require('src/js/data/data.json').media; // media was the name of the object I needed from the json file`

Which left my gulp task for `gulp-ejs` looking like this

```
gulp.task('ejs', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/views/pages/index.ejs')
    .pipe(ejs(
      {},
      { ext:'.html' }))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});
```

In case anyone is using `gulp-ejs` and is running into problems, you have to leave an empty object where you *would* import any data, even if you aren't.